# Are the terraform.tf and main.tf naming conventions or mandatory?

Tags: terraform

Most terraform projects I have come across have a file called terraform.tf and Main.tf Are these files mandatory or just naming conventions?

Comment: `main.tf` exists sometimes in root module configs. `terraform.tf` was the old convention for what is now commonly `versions.tf`.

Comment: No, they are not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the comment responses have already mentioned, they are just naming conventions. In some cases it might make more sense to avoid main.tf entirely (where a file named after a feature makes more sense).

The old conventions of __provider.tf or terraform.tf aren't recommended anymore. As Matt said, versions.tf should contain the terraform block with Terraform and provider configuration blocks but outside of that it's entirely up to you. main.tf is still common for implementation (e.g. module calls, main config outside of data or locals, a loop on variables creating resources, etc); it's effectively the entrypoint, if people are going to look at any .tf file first, it's main.tf so consider that in how you write your code.

Comment: `versions.tf` is just a naming convention also. You can place the terraform and provider configurations in any file, it doesn't have to be named `versions`

Comment: "versions.tf should contain the terraform block with Terraform and provider configuration blocks" - Can you provide any references on that?
This explanation on purpose of `versions.tf` and `provider.tf` offered by one of Terraform developer in 2023 is quite different to what your answer states: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/best-provider-tf-versions-tf-placement/56581/5